Implementation List Questions
It seems we have had a few questions recently asking for references on implementations. For example:

Are there any Implementations of Secure Indexes?
How to implement order preserving encryption or order preserving hashing (which isn't really about how to implement it, but if implementations exist)
Practical implementations of Multiparty computations

Are these sorts of questions off-topic here? Should we update the FAQ to address this? Is there another SE site these should be migrated to?
Update 1
Here is another example: Any practical implementation of homomorphic hashing?
Update 2
Here is yet another example: Ciphertext-Policy Attribute-Based Encryption Java Implementation

They seem on-topic to me (if they meet all our other criteria, like asking an answerable question, with well-defined criteria for evaluation of the answer, and they "show their work").  I don't see a problem with these questions.  I suggest we treat them as on-topic.

They are answerable if an implementation exists. Otherwise it is hard for anyone to say "no, no implementation exists". Also, if I say yes implementation X exists and you say implementation Y exists, how do you evaluate the two answers?

And the FAQ clearly states implementation questions "probably" belong on Security, so perhaps the FAQ should be addressed.

@Thomas, FWIW I asked on Security's meta.

My leaning would be to close the questions as off-topic just like we close list questions. As to another SE site, I am not sure.
